# IIS 7 url rewrite module on web.config

Tags: asp.net, url, web-config, url-rewriting

can anybody help me with this please. I have IIS7 and the hosting says that the URL Rewrite module has been installed already. I even put into the bin directory the Microsoft.Web.Iis.Rewrite.dll

i can only use the web.config for the url rewrite configuration since I dont have access to the IIS manager (hosting restriction).

here is my code on the web.config:

```
    <system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Rewrite to list_cities.aspx">
    <match url="^/state/([a-zA-Z]+)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="~/list_cities.aspx?state={R:1}" />
      </rule>             
   </rules>
 </rewrite>  
</system.webServer>
```

I still get the error, HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found, when i go to 
http://xxxxxxxx.com/state/CA/ . I have already searched the issue but I cant seem to find any solutions.

Can anybody please check my code. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution just now (not being an IIS expert...) 
Change {R:1} for {R:0}

```
     <system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <rule name="Rewrite to list_cities.aspx">
    <match url="^/state/([a-zA-Z]+)" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="~/list_cities.aspx?state={R:0}" />
      </rule>             
   </rules>
 </rewrite>  
</system.webServer>
```